# CPU racing at 30% or more in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I have window 7 64 bit Lenovo i7 with 8gb ram and 160gb ssd. I have virtual box version 4.1.16 installed (most latest to my knowledge)

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 as a guest inside of virtualbox. I have tried a couple of times now. It installs and "works" but the cpu in the guest os with no applications running is between 30% and 100%. The host machine is running without any slow downs. I have tried all sorts of different settings from within ubuntu and on virtualbox. But ubuntu continues to race.

Has anyone experienced this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the virtual guest extensions inside your vm? Your system seems to have more than enough power to have a better expirence. You may also try to enable multi processing in the options.

Comment: I have tried giving it 2 cpu's then virtualbox requires io apic and it does boot for me with that setting checked. I just set it to unity 2d and that seems to be a little better but still cpu is running.

Comment: Are you saying Ubuntu's system tools are reporting 30-100% usage of the CPU or that task manager tells you that the virtualbox application running Ubuntu is using 30-100% of the CPU from the host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my issues appears to have been being caused by NOT running in ubuntu 2d and a setting in the bios (VT-x). Once I changed the setting in the bios. The performance became drastically better and I also was then able to allow for 2 cpu's.

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: did you enable or disable the VT-x setting to increase performance?

Comment: enabled them in the bios

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem.

⠀Host: Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit)
⠀Guest: Windows 7 (64-bit)

Even with the virtualization turned on in host BIOS the CPU load was constantly around 40-50% in guest idle state.

What helped me was installing Guest Addition with Direct 3D support (you need to do that in safe mode) and turning on the host I/O Cache of the SATA controller.

So my current settings are:

**System**
⠀Base memory: **4096 Mb** (8192 Mb total host memory)
⠀Processor: **6 CPUs** (of host 6 CPUs)
⠀PAE/NX: **Enabled**
⠀VT-x/AMD-V: **Enabled**
⠀Nested Paging: **Enabled**

**Display**
⠀Video memory: **128 Mb**
⠀3D Acceleration: **Enabled**
⠀2D Acceleration: **Enabled**

Works like a charm! Virtual Box Version: 4.3.18_Ubuntu r96516